# Hibernate EhCache : Get All Entry in 2nd Level Cache

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

How do I get all entries available in 2nd Level Cache?

My application do a re-cache by cache.removeAll(); and list all() so in the Hibernate 2nd Level. It will have all the entries I need cached.

and During this 15 mins.. I only wish to getAll Entries from the 2nd level (without hitting DB)

I do no wish use hibernate query because the under lining change often.

What other options do I have?

Comment: im guessing you are having a 15 minute timeout for the cache.. you can use the `CacheManager` to get access to the cache and list items in the cache.

Comment: they are stored in de-hydrated mode.

Comment: have you tried to get all cache elemensts... http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#getAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: yes like I say they are stored in De-hydrated.. so it won't be the actual element. and how do you get All Elements from EHCache? there is not getAll().. only getAll(collection<keys>)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to achieve this by using:

Assume my key is a String:

```
List keys = Ehcache.getKeysWithExpiryCheck();
List<ABC> abcList = new ArrayList();

for(Object key = keys){
    String k = (String)((CacheKey) key).getKey();
    abcList.add(dao.get(k));
}
```

dao.get() will hit the cache first before database.

=) If anyone got any better solution please let me know.